# Which TransferRepresentation should be used for sharing a PDF using ShareLink? DataRepresentation, FileRepresentation, ProxyRepresentation, etc?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

I am trying to use ShareLink to share a multi-page PDF that I've created and also stored locally as a .pdf file. The extension that I'm using to make the PDF transferable is as follows:

```
extension PDFDocument: Transferable {
   public static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
      DataRepresentation(exportedContentType: .pdf) { pdf in 
         return pdf.dataRepresentation() ?? Data() 
      }
   }
}
```

This seems to work for items like Messages, Mail, AirDrop, and Save to Files in the share sheet that's presented. It does NOT work for Print (nothing happens when clicked and the share sheet is just dismissed). However, it does work for Print with HP Smart (I have an HP printer in addition to a laser printer). My questions are as follows:

1. Is DataRepresentation the correct TransferRepresentation to use for PDFs or should I be using FileRepresentation or ProxyRepresentation?
2. Is there a way to limit/customize the automatic share sheet that pops up so that "other options" like Markup, Twitter, Facebook, etc. are not shown?
3. If DataRepresentation is the correct TransferRepresentation to use for PDFs, am I missing something? I've seen others include multiple DataRepresentation statements (see below) in their code but I'm not sure what it's really doing because my results don't seem any different.

```
    public static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(contentType: .pdf) { pdf in
            pdf.dataRepresentation() ?? Data()
        } importing: { data in
            if let pdf = PDFDocument(data: data) {
                return pdf
            } else {
                return PDFDocument()
            }
        }
        DataRepresentation(exportedContentType: .pdf) { pdf in 
            return pdf.dataRepresentation() ?? Data() }
        }
    }
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I was unable to get an extension using TransferRepresentation to work. Some features in the resulting share sheet (Markup and Print) would not work correctly. So, after filing a TSI with Apple and working with one of their developers, I ended up rewriting some of my code and just using the url for my PDF for item: in the ShareLink instead. There may be a way to do this also using TransferRepresentation but I could not (at present) get the Markup and Print buttons on the share sheet to work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I need to be able to print my PDF, but it doesn't even show up when sharing via a ShareLink. I tried by creating a PDF struct and extending with Transferable but that gave me 0 share options in the ShareView.

Comment: @John - I skipped the transferrable extension and instead saved my pdf locally and then referenced the url (url already conforms to transferable) in the ShareLink. ShareLink("Share?", item: model.url, subject: Text("subject"), message: Text("message")). Hope that helps a bit.